# AngularJs directives issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created two directives and included them in my html. However, only the first one executes and nothing after it.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div directive-one=""/> 
        <div directive-two=""/>
        <div> Hello I am {{name}} and I am {{age}} years old!</div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
        <div>Name: <input type='text' ng-model='name'/></div>
    </script>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Jason";
    $scope.age = "20";
});

app.directive('directiveOne', function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        template: "<div>Age: <input type = 'text' id = 'age' ng-model='age'>
                  </input></div>"
    }
});

app.directive('directiveTwo', function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "myTemplate.html"
    }
```

});

Here is the fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/harishmodugu/PMgTf/13/)

Can't figure out what the issue is. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to close your div tags with the directives in them and you don't need the ="" after either.

```
<div directive-one></div> 
<div directive-two></div>
```

[Here's an updated fiddle with it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/PMgTf/14/)

Comment: That was dumb. Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised why this is not consider as close of element . it has "/" at the end -  <div directive-one=""/> 
        <div directive-two=""/>